# firebase phone authentication "We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later."

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am developing and testing an app. I am getting the following message when I was expecting a text with the 6 digit pen.

> {code: "auth/too-many-requests", message: "We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later."}

so I tried going to `authentication` => `Sign-in method` => `phone` and add a # for testing but i get the following error

> error adding test phone number

Does anyone know how to get arround either one of these issues so i can continue testing my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Per the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers), you cannot add the phone number of an existing user. You should delete the user that is using your phone number before you can add it to the whitelist.